# Self join sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following table which stores records of merged projects .
Here Merge1 is primary project and Merge2 is secondary project which means Merge2 gets merged into Merge1 .

```
Merge1  Merge2
------------------
1        2
3        1
4        3
4        8
9        6
7        9
```

Now i want to write a query which will return the contents of particular project say project id 4.
here project 4 contains 8,3,1 &2 .

How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: Are circular situations possible?

Comment: This type of query is typically encountered when dealing with a Bill Of Materials (BOM). A search using that term and SQL Server should find plenty of examples.

Comment: @dan1111 : circular situation means ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : can you please provide me any useful links ?

Comment: @punter - dan's question is, I think, could there be an additional row, given your sample data, containing e.g. `2,3` as `Merge1,Merge2` - i.e. you could then follow a circular chain from 3->1, 1->2, 2->3, 3->1 and so on.

Comment: @punter You can consider using recursive CTEs

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Nope that situation is not possible . Once a project is merged with any project it can not be merged with any other project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query which gives required result. ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c2f29/1))

```
with cte_merge (projectid)
AS
(
  select merge2 from testBOM where merge1=4
  UNION  ALL
  select merge2 from testBOM inner join cte_merge on testBOM.merge1 = cte_merge.projectid
)
select * from cte_merge
```

Hope it helps you.